# How to transfer text from one file to another using java I/O

Tags: java

I have this code for transferring text from one file to another, but it's not working. It only transfer the second and the third letter from the first file to the second and not the whole text. Can anyone help me?

```
FileInputStream br=new FileInputStream(ss);
     FileOutputStream rb=new FileOutputStream(sd);
     while(br.read()!=-1){
          rb.write(br.read());
    }
     if(br!=null)
         br.close();
     if(rb!=null)
         rb.close();

}
```

Comment: What do you think happens to the characters you read in your `while`s condition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every `read` reads a byte, since you do two reads in the loop you ignore every second byte.

You need to do something like this:

```
int b;
while ((b=br.read()) != -1) {
    rb.write(b);
}
```

Even better would be to use a larger buffer to read and write the bytes in order to have fewer read and write calls.